# HTML problem print table with custom header

Tags: html, css

I want to print html table and repeat custom header on all of pages .
this is my example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
        @media print
        {
            table { page-break-inside:auto }
            tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
            td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
            thead { display:table-header-group }
            tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>family</td>
        <td>age</td>
        <td>address</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mahdi</td>
        <td>Hosseini</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Tehran</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Javad</td>
        <td>Mohammadi</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>
            Shiraz <br>
            Shiraz <br>
            Shiraz <br>
            // Repeat line to take big cell
            Shiraz <br>
            Shiraz <br>
            Shiraz <br>
            Shiraz <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 1 :
[image]

But page 2 result this problem !
[image]

table vertical lines writed on header cell .
How can fix this problem or maybe you have a another idea ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using an HTML renderer such as a browser?

Comment: adding `<tbody>` does change anything? I ask because I see you used thead and maybe the rest of your table should be in `<tbody>`

Comment: I used google chrome for test this table , also I used <tbody> but does not work !

Comment: anyway trying that code as is inside both latest versions of firefox and chrome works correctly as expected. The header is repeated on each page and the layout isn't scrambled. So it's unclear why you are having issues. By the way the `border=1` on the table is invalid nowadays despite the browser will deal with it setting borders to all table parts.

Comment: What ?! , my question is unclear ! , I press Ctrl + P , so you can see something like second picure on your browser .